# Is it possible to create button by reading a saved file in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a button which will toggle the frame to be visible or hidden and the frame contains a few buttons inside.

I have a saved file where I'll store the name of the buttons I would like to display.

Is there any possible way where I could use the saved file to create the buttons to be displayed (in the case of multiple files)

At the moment I could only pre-create the buttons

Comment: short answer yes. Long answer is that you'll have to keep a track of a lot of things - button text, command, position, etc

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 is there any possible reference material regarding this, still very new to python and Tkinter

Comment: I'm not able to get what you're trying to achieve here but from what I could understand, you have a saved file which has some names written to it. You want your python script to be able to create buttons with the names that are saved to the file. Is that right, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @PSSolanki Yup you're right

Comment: @Hensley Hmm. How about you provide me a sample txt file that you want to create your buttons from.That actually doesn't sound too difficult.

Comment: @PSSolanki Sample text: https://pastebin.com/raw/hgAqfW8N
So each new line will contain a new button to be created

Comment: @Hensley I see. So you need buttons having the text described in file. I'm writing an answer (of course after I succeed ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on what you described and the sample text file you provided, here is a (not the best) working solution for you. Must read the comments in code snippet to understand what I did.

To summarize though, just read the file, save the data in a `variable` (may be `list`, `dict` or whatever). Then use those `variables` to create `widgets`.

If I missed some point in the question or I misunderstood the question, do let me know.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # for python 3.x
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk  # for python 2.x

# a function to create buttons. Optional if you don't plan to
# give these buttons a command (I'm sure you will but it's up to you)
def createButton(buttonName):
    tk.Button(root, text=buttonName).pack()

# reading the file content
with open('test.txt') as file:
    buttonNames = file.read().split()
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

# Looping through the names that were in the file
for buttonName in buttonNames:
    createButton(buttonName)

root.mainloop()
```

a sample image of program for the text file you provided ::

[image: altText=IMGUR didn't do it]

Comment: Thanks alot!! Apology for the late response. I will take a look into this and adapt it accordingly. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Hensley No worries :) . Just FYI, as you're a new contributor to SO, it's a customary on Stack Overflow to upvote an answer if it was helpful. And accept the answer if it solves the problem or answers the question. You can do that from the top left portion of any answer frame.